# Cmake with Qt: Clang: error: no such file or directory ' " ', /bin/sh: ": command not found

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cmake

After using CMake to generate a makefile for the Qt project I am working on, when I use the make command to build the program, it cannot find the files that it needs. Here are the error messages:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: ' " '
clang: error: no input files
/bin/sh ": command not found
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/2d_cell_sim_2d_cell_sim.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/2d_cell_sim_2d_cell_sim.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(2d_cell_sim)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.0)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS “${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}”)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_2d_cell_sim
    main.cpp
    root.cpp
    cell.cpp
    view.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    scene.cpp
    robot.cpp
    startupdialog.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_2d_cell_sim Qt5::Widgets)
```

I'm not sure why it seems to be looking for a folder titled "... or maybe I am misinterpreting the error messages. I would appreciate any help, as I am a beginner to CMake!

Comment: Don't link to error messages (or anything else that's relevant to the question). Put them directly *in* the question, as *text*.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it to change that. This was my first post ever, so I wasn't aware of the proper way to post things.

Comment: No harm done. Thank you for the edit. You may want to read : https://stackoverflow.com/tour ,    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unlike to shell scripts, in CMake assignments do not uses equal sign (see assignment to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CMake only *standard* double quotes (`"`) have special meaning. Non-standard ones (`“`) are treated as usual character.

In other words, **do not use non-standard double quotes** in CMake scripts.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you so much! I tried to vote up your answer but since I have less than 15 reputation score it won't show publicly.